# Noise Coupling methods to communication cables

Tags: signal, noise, signal-processing, coax, noise-spectral-density

I want to know how can I **couple noise(practically)** into a communication cable in order to analyze the data error rate of the communication.
I hope by using transformer I can couple it, but I don't know the rating of transformer used. I am using coaxial(shielded) cable of 1000ft, RS485 standard and modbus protocol.

Comment: Differential or common mode noise?

Comment: @Andyaka I need effect of both type for analysis

Comment: You could use a capacitive clamp method or a toroidal magnetic coupler for common-mode injection.

Comment: @Andyaka Sir, can I use current probe for coupling noise into the cable ? whether can we use transformer in any means for common mode noise coupling?

Comment: The devil is in the detail - part numbers and data sheets are needed to assess this.

Comment: @Andyaka Hi..I am planning to use 50/5A CT, for coupling white noise.  I am going to connect the secondary with noise. I hope it will couple.

Comment: It should couple but check the frequency response of the CT - it may be somewhat limited if you don't choose the correct part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magnetic coupling injection: -

[image]

Picture taken from [here](http://www.compliance-club.com/archive/old_archive/011021.htm).

Capacitive clamp coupler: -

[image]

Picture taken from [here](http://www.scientificindia.com/products/CDNEMCL-20-Accessories-EM-clamp-for-immunity-tests.aspx).

For differential injection of a voltage in series with the inner conductor in the coax I would use a high frequency, low impedance pulse transformer with the secondary in series with the coax inner conductor either at the feed end or the receive end. Something like this should work: -

[image]

The basic idea is that the transformer injects across a low impedance in series with the coax inner cable. You can probably use something as low as 1 ohm as the injection impedance so that the transmission line termination impedances are not unduly affected.

In principle it's the same as this for testing power supply noise except the power supply is the data system: -

[image]